# Replacing string vector entries with some predetermined numerical values in R

Tags: r, str-replace, gsub

Suppose I have two vectors of the form `vec1 = c("AAA","AA+","","D")` and `vec2 = c("AAA","","D","AA+")`. I want to replace `"AAA" = 1, "AA+" = 2, "D" = 3, and finally blanks with zeros`

Thus I want to create two more vectors based upon `vec1 and vec2` which I will be referring to for my further analysis.
The transformed form of `Vec1` should be in form like - `v1 = (1,2,0,3)`  and for `vec2` it should be as -`v2 =(1,0,3,2)`

Answer (score 1):

Use `mapply` and `match`:

```
> as.vector(mapply(function(x) match(x, c("", "AAA", "AA+", "D")) - 1, vec1))
[1] 1 2 0 3
```

Or if you're fine with it not being a vector:

```
> mapply(function(x) match(x, c("", "AAA", "AA+", "D")) - 1, vec1)
AAA AA+       D 
  1   2   0   3 
>
```

Comment: Thank You Very Much. In this regard, if possible can u help me to do the reverse substitution, i.e., given v1 = c(1,2,0,3), I want to get back my original vec1 = c("AAA","AA+","","D"). It would be of great help to me then.

Comment: @DebojitRoy I recommend you to ask a new question, and accept this one.

Answer (score 1):

We may use vectorized option with a named vector

```
vec1new <- setNames(c(1, 2, 3), c("AAA", 'AA+', 'D'))[vec1]
vec1new[is.na(vec1new)] <- 0
```

Comment: Thank You. The mechanism works for the reverse substitution as well which I was looking for now. It's great.